# How to get network provided date and time without internet connection on a device in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

Pls I want to get network date and time on my app to set  expiring date without using web server's date and system date. I want to use network date on the phone. pls how can I come about this in cn1? I need a snippet code to invoke this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support that. You might be able to use a [native interface](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to accomplish that but I think most devices won't support it and Android would require a "scary" phone system permission to get that.

Comment: Shai Almog thanks for your response. which way can you suggest for setting of expiring date in CN1?

Comment: Just check the date and to prevent cheating make sure the clock doesn't go backwards. This might have issues with daylight saving but that's a rare occasion